# Jquery full calendar with events from sql database

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Can anyone give sample code in which there is interaction of jquery fullcalendar with the database

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a way for fullcalendar to interact with the database.  You need to write some server-side software to support the fullcalendar requests.

You need to handle your own sql queries, as fullcalendar will just make requests to a URL looking for the event data, looking for JSON.

Check out here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/